# Sending HTTP Headers doesn't appear in $_SERVER

Tags: php

I try sending custom HTTP header from [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com) but the server doesn't recognize it in

```
isset($_SERVER["HTTP_AUTH_TOKEN"]
```

returns false, also I tried

```
var_dump($_SERVER)
```

and my parameter isn't there

However, it works fine on localhost, but it won't work when I upload it on godaddy hosting for example?

The suggested solution doesn't work for me..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [enable Apache http Authorization header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37158714/enable-apache-http-authorization-header)

Comment: Could you show us some code, please? Or at least dump the Postman headers?

Comment: I had the same problem and the linked question solved mine (my server was a Apache instance)

Comment: @cramopy can you please tell me should I put it inside the <IfModule> tag or not?

Comment: @MahmoudTarek Just add a extra line in your htaccess file and write it there.

Comment: this doesn't work @cramopy

Comment: @Mawg there's no code my man, I try to dump the headers and my sent headers aren't there, that's all. They work on localhost but not on server

Comment: No code on the server to access the hearers?  Can you at less copy/paste what Postman is sending? Otherwise it's just a guessing gane

Comment: @Mawg HYG, https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjrc4.png

Comment: Do you control both sides of the interface? Does it need to be in the header, or can you use GET or POST?

Comment: I control both sides yes, but it has to be header as it's auth values and sometimes the request is GET.

Comment: Even so, if the token is only valid for a session, is it a major risk to send it with GET? Sorry, but I can't see anything wrong with your header & am trying to thin of a workaround :-/

Comment: Yeah I understand you, well I wanted to solve the problem not do a workaround as I'm not in a hurry, thanks for your support though man :)

Comment: Then, let's keep trying :-) best to do it "correctly" if you can. Did you try [getallheaders()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php)?  Did you `var_dump($_SERVER)`? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541430/how-do-i-read-any-request-header-in-php) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403670/how-can-i-get-php-to-display-the-headers-it-received-from-a-browser)

Comment: Yeah I tried both, it seems that I found the solution.. look below

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157226/discussion-between-mahmoudtarek-and-mawg).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();        
$headers['HTTP_AUTH_TOKEN'];
```

It worked for me.

Comment: only if it's as Apache module

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

The problem was in adding extra _ symbol in the header variable, worked fine when I set the variable with no _ symbol..

Comment: I should have realized when I looked at your image o the headers at https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjrc4.png  It says `headers(3)`, but you only show 2, so I guess that you cut off the one that would have let us help you. Did you learn anything from that, or your next question?

Comment: The last one was the content-type, that doesn't change anything